# Voronoï summation for cusp forms with characters

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

In an attempt to solve an unrelated problem, I was led to the task of estimating/bounding from above sums of the form
$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty\lambda(m)e\left(-\frac{am}{q}\right)h(m)$$
where $\sum_{m=1}^\infty\lambda(m)e(mz)$ is the Fourier expansion of a cusp form of weight $1$ and a certain level $N$, with respect to some Dirichlet character $\chi$, and $h$ is some smooth compactly supported function. Note that the modulus of $\chi$ is NOT (necessarily) $q$; I need to work with the above display for a general positive integer $q$.

Now, my knowledge of all things modular is rather limited, but my understanding is that sums like the above are best handled via some variation of Voronoï summation. However, I have not been able to find a specific formulation of Voronoï summation in the literature that suits my situation. For example, in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304187.pdf, Theorem 4.12 only deals with cusp forms with respect to the full modular group (or at least this is my understanding - I do not master the language used at the beginning of Section 4). In Iwaniec and Kowalski's *Analytic Number Theory*, Exercise 9 in Chapter 4 deals with the case of modular forms twisted by characters, but still, as far as I understand, only with respect to the full modular group (e.g. level $1$) and when the modulus of $\chi$ divides $q$.

It is possible that, for experts, it is clear how to handle the sum I presented via one of these two versions, but I do not see how to do it and I would appreciate any suggestion on general principles regarding approaches to this sum.

Comment: Does Lemma 2.4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01576.pdf do what you need?

Comment: That lemma equates the sum that the OP is studying to an even more complicated expression involving three sums and an integral. In particular, it gives no upper bound for the OP's sum.

Comment: _In an attempt to solve an unrelated problem, I was led to..._ - Doesn't that mean it's not unrelated?

Comment: What is the support of $h$ here? Is $h$ a _fixed_ test function? Then the sum is trivially $O(1)$. Also, you need to specify which parameters ($\pi$, $N$, $q$, $C(\chi)$, etc.) are fixed and which are varying.

Comment: @m34 At a first glance it seems to be the sort of thing I want, yes, thank you very much! Other remarks are still welcome, of course :)

Comment: @SubhajitJana, on a first approximation you may think of $h(x)=f(x/B)$ where $f$ is a fixed compactly supported function and $B$ is some parameter tending to infinity, so upper bounds should depend on $B$. Here $\chi$ is fixed, and so is $N$ (the cusp form itself is fixed) but $q$ is varying.

Comment: @Kimball I guess :)

Comment: You usually expect square-root cancellation, that is, the expected bound is $\ll_{q,\epsilon} B^{1/2+\epsilon}$ with polynomial dependency in $q$ which follows from some Voronoi formula. In this particular case, using the Kirillov model one can show the sum is $O(\sqrt{B})$ uniformly in $q$.

Comment: @SubhajitJana can you please give more details? I am not familiar with the Kirillov model, and knowing how to obtain such a bound could be extremely helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the cuspidal representation $\pi:=\pi_f\otimes\pi_\infty$ of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A})$ with the central character $\omega_\chi$, the Hecke character attached to $\chi$, such that $\pi_f$ has level $N$ and $\pi_\infty$ is isomorphic to the Discrete series of weight $k$. Let $\phi\in\pi$ be a Hecke-normalized factorizable even newform with the Whittaker function $W_\phi=\otimes_{p\le\infty}W_p$ (in this case, $W_p$ is the normalized (that is $W_p(1)=1$) newvector of $\pi_p$) such that $$W_\infty\left[\begin{pmatrix}y&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\right]=f(y),$$
where $f$ is the test function mentioned in the comment. The last restriction is possible via the Theory of the Kirillov model: $$C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^\times)\subset\left\lbrace W\left[\begin{pmatrix}\cdot&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\right]\mid W\in\pi_\infty\right\rbrace.$$
The Fourier expansion of $\phi$ is given by
$$\phi(g)=\sum_{\gamma\in\mathbb{Q}^\times}W\left[\begin{pmatrix}\gamma&\\&1\end{pmatrix}g\right].$$
If $$g=\left(1,\begin{pmatrix}1&-a/q\\&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1/B&\\&1\end{pmatrix}\right)\in\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_f)\times\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R}),$$
then
$$\phi(g) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\lambda(m)}{\sqrt{m}}e\left(-\frac{am}{q}\right)f(m/B).$$
Note that using $\lambda(m)\ll m^{O(1)}$ one can truncate the above sum by $m\le B^{1+\epsilon}$ with $O(B^{-N})$ error.
Using the bound $\|\phi\|_\infty\ll_\pi 1$ we conclude that the sum in the OP is $O(B^{1/2+\epsilon})$.